# How do I perform interlocked comparison of an enum in C?

Tags: c

Is it possible to use interlocked compare exchange to atomically read an `enum` value in C?

Comment: Probably — if you store the values in integer variables which support atomic interlocked compare/exchange to get the desired result.  If your question is "will a variable of an `enum` type be a type which supports atomic interlocked compare/exchange?", then the answer depends on your compiler and hardware, and that information is signally missing.  I'm having to guess at what you mean anyway — the 'interlock' part is not terminology I'm familiar with.

Comment: Sometimes. What architecture and compiler are you using?